# Selenium - Java - How to check button is enabled or not?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried so many times `isenabled` property but it always return "true" as the button is disabled on the page but it still return "True"
Please suggest the workaround to handle this?

Here is the code:

```
public void OpenSearchPage_and_verifyaddtofavoriteslink() throws InterruptedException 
{
    try

        {
            driver.navigate().to(favouritepagelink);
            driver.findElement(FavoritesCheckBoxSelectAll).click();

            //verify condition if product exist on favorites page

            if(driver.findElement(FavoritesDelConditionCheck).isEnabled())
            {
                System.out.println("Enter in condition");

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Out of condition");
            }
        }

    catch(Exception ex)

        {
            System.out.println("SearchPage not opened: " +ex.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML for the button so that better debugging can be done.

Comment: ... also identify the webdriver you are using, there is slight differences in behaviour.

Comment: what about checking the button on attribute clickable?

Comment: Yeah Sure here is the html response.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn inactive">Delete</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn cancel inactive">Cancel</a></div></div></div></div>

Comment: @MartinSpamer - I am not getting your point?

Comment: @pburgr - How to do this?

Comment: The behavior of Html is different when button is enable or disable :
Html response is :
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Delete</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn cancel inactive">Cancel</a></div></div></div></div>

When button is disable:
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn inactive">Delete</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn cancel inactive">Cancel</a></div></div></div></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

There can two reasons for getting this issue:
i) Issue with object 
ii) Issue with the property

I) Issue with object: We can ensure we are using the right object for the button
and refresh the object before performing the operation

ii) Issue with property: Please check if some other property other then enabled is indicating this behaviour by verifying the html code behaviour.

Comment: For point 2: There is no other property.
For point 1: I am using the right object. Here is code :

 if(driver.findElement(FavoritesDeleteBtn).click())
    {
     System.out.println("Enter in condition");
     /*driver.navigate().to(favouritepagelink);
     Thread.sleep(18000);
     driver.findElement(FavoritesCheckBoxSelectAll).click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     driver.findElement(FavoritesDeleteBtn).click();
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     driver.findElement(FavoritesModalDelBtn).click();
     Thread.sleep(10000);
     
    }*/

Comment: Instead of using .IsEnabled directly, please use .getAttribute('disabled')) as isenabled might not work correctly in case of disabled elements.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved :)

I have used getattribute to get class name then apply condition based on class attribute and its working fine.

Thank you all for the help :)